# Find williams fractals in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array whose values coincide with the high prices of the currency on the candlestick chart, and I need to find williams fractals in this chart.
But I don't quite understand the algorithm for finding these fractals.

```
     for(let i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
     {
        let mr2=[]
        for(let j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            mr2.push(myArray[i+j])
        }
        if(mr2[2]==Math.max.apply(null, mr2))
        {
            if(myArray.indexOf(mr2[2])>0)
            {
                max.push(myArray.indexOf(mr2[2]))
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to find them with this method, but I feel that it does not fit

Comment: do you have some data and wanted result?

Comment: I'm taking data from the api https://fcsapi.com/, but no result yet